# CanCan and ActiveRecord. How to limit file downloads to a certain role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancan

If I have an Admin and SuperAdmin role. How can I limit downloads to the SuperAdmin only.

```
index download_links: current_user.super_admin? do
    column :email
    column :query
    default_actions
end
```

Gives the following error for current_user and current_admin_user:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:
```

Anyway to extract this into CanCan user ability? Also even when I hide the links for a certain user, going to URL.csv still downloads the links. Who can I block this?

Comment: 'download_links' is your custom method in ActiveAdmin right?

Comment: No it's an ActiveAdmin method @AnantKolvankar

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `current_user.super_admin?` in a Proc.

```
index download_links: ->{ current_user.super_admin? } do
    column :email
    column :query
    default_actions
end
```

Comment: I ended up going another route. The download links helper is sort of useless from a security stand point. It gets rid of the links, but doesn't block that user from just entering the format in the address bar.

Comment: I know, there is a issue and a PR for that.